# What's wrong with this format string?

Tags: java, android, string, format

I have a string like this:

```
<string name="q_title" formatted="false">Item %d of %d</string>
```

I'm using it in String.format like this:

```
String log = String.format(getString(R.string.q_title), 100, 500);
```

So far I've observed no problems with the output.

However, code inspection in Android Studio gives me:

> Format string 'q_title' is not a valid format string so it
>   should not be passed to String.format

Why?

Comment: take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Comment: What if you remove the backslashes before the double quotes?

Comment: Could you update your question with the new string?

Comment: take a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39758)

Comment: @blackbelt Heh, so somehow they haven't integrated the same into Android Studio yet. I'm no one to judge but how they do their business with Android Studio it is strange. If you wish I could accept that as an aswer.

Comment: yes it is really strange.  I switched back to eclipse again, waiting for better time

Comment: some people said it got fixed on ADT 21. however, i have ADT 22 and i still see this weird behaviour, and need to use formatted="false" for each string tag that has "%" .

Comment: By the way you will get the same error message if you use <xliff:g> (tag using for translation strings) in the string.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your string should be

```
<string name="q_title" formatted="false">Item %1$d of %2$d</string>
```

And code

```
String log = getString(R.string.q_title, 100, 500);
```

When you have multiple arguments you need to mark them with 1$, 2$... n$. In arabian langs order is reversed, so they need to know how to change it correctly.

`getString(id, args...)` perform format in itself.

Answer (score 10):

For percent, the following worked for me.

```
<string name="score_percent">%s%%</string>


getString(R.string.score_percent,"20")
```

If you are dealing with integers replace s by d

```
<string name="score_percent">%d%%</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those still looking for this answer, as the [link that Blackbelt posted](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) implies, the correct format for the string would be:

```
<string name="q_title">Item %1$d of %2$d</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to format your strings, then you can do so by putting your format arguments in the string resource, as demonstrated by the following example resource.

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

In this example, the format string has two arguments: %1$s is a string and %2$d is a 
decimal number. Then, format the string by calling getString(int, Object...). For example:

```
String text = getString(R.string.welcome_messages, username, mailCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware to escape all special characters

I had a problem with this string because I forgot to escape the percentage character " % " at the end .

```
<string name="market_variation_formatter">%s %</string>
```

The good escaped string was :

```
<string name="market_variation_formatter">%s \%</string>
```