# Unable to place format specifier in the strings.xml file in android

Tags: android

My app supports both English and Arabic language. So, I placed strings in **strings.xml** files for both language separately. I need a formatted string, for that I used the format specifiers in the **strings.xml** file(see below string). I can place the format specifier correctly in the English language file but unable to place the format specifier correctly in the Arabic language file.

```
<string name="device_offline_message" formatted="false">%s is offline. Please make sure it is online to execute the action.</string>
```

In Arabic, I can't place the string at the end of the string. Even if I specify the formatter in the start of the text, the `lint` check shows an error in the java code like

> Format string 'device_offline_message' is not a valid format string so
>   it should not be passed to String.format

in the below line of code where I used the string

```
showToastAlertDialog(String.format(getString(R.string.device_offline_message), device.getShortName()));
```

Comment: Use %1$s in arabic strings.xml. Ref: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502824/whats-wrong-with-this-format-string

Comment: @Raghavendra This is my arabic string. <string name="device_offline_message" formatted = "false">s$1%.غير متصل. يرجى التأكد بأنه متصل لتنفيذ العمل</string>. When I place like this, I always get the java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: in the logcat.

Comment: @Madan <string name="device_offline_message" formatted = "false">%1$s.غير متصل. يرجى التأكد بأنه متصل لتنفيذ العمل</string> try this. I am not sure where exactly you want to replace the string though:)

Comment: @Raghavendra, It's working fine. Thank s

Answer (score 3):

use

```
<string name="device_offline_message" formatted="false"> %1$s is offline.  Please make sure it is online to execute the action.</string>
```

instead of

```
<string name="device_offline_message" formatted="false">%s is offline.  Please make sure it is online to execute the action.</string>
```

just like @Raghavendra said in the comment.

And make sure you have set up Android studio properly.

In android Studio 2, RTL support is not turned on by default, Configure it Manually:

1. In your Computer, go to the [android-studio2.0]/bins/idea.properties
2. add editor.new.rendering=true to the end of idea.properties
3. restart your android Studio

More Information here: [How to edit arabic string properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242279/how-to-edit-arabic-string-properly)

Comment: This is my arabic string. <string name="device_offline_message" formatted = "false">.غير متصل. يرجى التأكد بأنه متصل لتنفيذ العملs%
    </string>